# Finding family of functions satisfying equation

Tags: definite-integrals, periodic-functions

Is there a family of functions $g_{n}(t)$ (labelled by an integer index $n$ ) that satisfy the following equation?:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{0}^{T}dt g_{n}(t)e^{i(n-m)2\pi t/T}=0,
\end{eqnarray}
where $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $g_{n}(t+T)=g_{n}(t)$, e.g. it is a periodic function. The $g_{n}(t)$ family does not need to be necessarily real, they can be complex-valued functions. In fact, it is easier to define $y_{n}(t)=g_{n}(t)e^{in2\pi t/T}$, and so look for orthogonal functions to the complex exponential satisfying:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{0}^{T}dty_{n}(t)e^{-im2\pi t/T}=0.
\end{eqnarray}
The equation must work for any $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$ with the $y_{n}(t)\neq 0$.

Comment: This works with constant functions.

Comment: Yes, apart from the trivial case $g_{n}(t)=n$, which I think that is the one you are referring to.

Comment: So the question reduces to finding a family of functions such that the RHS is zero. Are the $g$ real ?

Comment: I have edited the question, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Then $g_n(t)e^{-in2\pi t/T}$ must be orthogonal to $e^{-im2\pi t/T}$. If I am right, by the Fourier series, the $g_n$ are identically zero.

Comment: But that would correspond again to the trivial case. What I am looking for is if there exists a family of functions $g_{n}(t)$ labelled by an index $n$ that satisfy the above. In other words, if one can find $\int_{0}^{T}dt g_{n}(t)\cos(q2\pi t/T)=+i\int_{0}^{T}dt g_{n}(t)\sin(q 2\pi t/T)$, with $g_{n}(t)$ being distinct from the trivial case $g_{n}(t)=0$, and this must work for any $n,q\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Didn't I answer ?